# looking for a way to simplify this if/else statement. javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

So, I have a function (i am workng with jquery ui and running this on drag event, though for this question I don't think that is important)

Basically I have the following repetitive `if else` code:

And  I am curious if there is a way to write this in one line(ish) and not have a 100 `else if` lines if I want to be able to support 100 steps (divisions of a total slider value).

```
 var thisPos =  $( ".sliderknob" ).position();

        var x = thisPos.left -  window['sliderhome'].left;

        console.log("(" + x + ")");

        l = Object.keys(obj_frameindex).length;

        framefraction = 290/l;

        if (x>-1 && x<framefraction){
            console.log('frame 1'); 
            frameselector(0); 
            $('#framecounter').html("FRAME " + 1);
        }
        else if (x>framefraction && x<framefraction*2){
            console.log('frame 2'); 
            frameselector(1); 
            $('#framecounter').html("FRAME " + 2);
        }
        else if (x>framefraction*2 && x<framefraction*3){
            console.log('frame 3'); 
            frameselector(2); 
            $('#framecounter').html("FRAME " + 3);
        }
        else if (x>framefraction*3 && x<framefraction*4){
           console.log('frame 4'); 
           frameselector(3); 
           $('#framecounter').html("FRAME " + 4);}    //etc..........
```

Showing only 4 here, but imagine it goes on...

Any ideas?

Comment: It might be easier if you spelt out the relationships in your `else if` statement. In the process, you might just hit upon the answer to your question.

Comment: What should happen if `x==framefraction` or `x==framefraction*2`…? Do you expect `x` really to become negative (or should that have been `x>=0`?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
var frameNo = Math.max(0, Math.floor(x / framefraction)) + 1;
console.log('frame ' + frameNo);
frameselector(frameNo - 1);
$('#framecounter').html('FRAME ' + frameNo);
```

Comment: this worked great. I can't say that i really grasp why/how that math.max function works.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like:

```
if x < 0 { return };
var f = Math.ceil(x / framefraction);
console.log(`frame` + f);
frameselector(f - 1);
$(`#framecounter`).html("FRAME " + f);
```